# Left JOIN of a VIEW with a Huge table with multiple columns taking too much time

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT r.*
     , u.archive 
  FROM records r
  LEFT 
  JOIN users_view u
    ON u.vocal_com_id = r.userid    
  LEFT 
  JOIN groups g
    ON u.group_id = g.id 
 WHERE date_time >= '2020-06-01 06:00:00 UTC' 
   AND date_time <= '2020-11-04 06:59:59 UTC' 
 ORDER 
    BY date_time DESC 
OFFSET 0 
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Note that queries against views in MySQL cannot use underlying indexes, rendering their utility questionable

Comment: And it's meaningless to outer join tables (groups, in this instance) from which you select no columns

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT r.*
     , u.archive 
  FROM records r
  LEFT 
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM users_view u  WHERE u.vocal_com_id IN (SELECT r.userid  FROM records r  WHERE date_time >= '2020-06-01 06:00:00 UTC' AND date_time <= '2020-11-04 06:59:59 UTC'  ) ) AS u
    ON u.vocal_com_id = r.userid    
  LEFT 
  JOIN groups g
    ON u.group_id = g.id 
 WHERE date_time >= '2020-06-01 06:00:00 UTC' 
   AND date_time <= '2020-11-04 06:59:59 UTC' 
 ORDER 
    BY date_time DESC 
OFFSET 0 
 LIMIT 10
```